# Sorting of "All Sites" list in Stack Exchange pulldown menu

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

I think it would be useful if this listed sites I had accounts on first so I can quickly jump between them.  Even better, it could sort them by my rep on each site so that the sites I use the most are at the top.

What is the current sorting method anyway?  Seems random to me.

Comment: It is random, to encourage users to visit other sites.  Originally it was sorted the same way as http://stackexchange.com/sites, but this meant that without scrolling users would only see two beta sites after SO, SU, SF, and MSO.

Comment: That's unfortunate that they designed it for what they wish users wanted rather than what they actually want.  If I have to hunt through the whole list to find a particular site, my response will be to stop using that list entirely, which means it doesn't achieve *either* goal.  I've been checking out lots of other sites all on my own, I don't need to be led about by the nose.

Comment: @David well, these days the HNQ sidebar is doing very good job of encouraging users to visit other sites. :)